# Уязвимости на стеке

Tags: c++, c++11

Имеется 5 направлений по теме "уязвимость в стеке":

1. Эксплуатация с испол. стеком и jmp esp в коде.
2. Эксплуатация с jmp esp в коде, функцией mprotect (VirtualProtect) в бинарнике и несполняемым стеком.
3. Обход security_cookie/stack_canary путём изменения локальных переменных, передаваемых в подфункцию той, где мы осуществили переполнение.
4. Обход -/-/- путём модификации обработчика исключений.
5. Обход -/-/- -/-/- при условии активного SEHOP.

Из них надо выбрать любые 2 темы.

**Задача**: для каждой темы (из выбранных двух) придумать приложение с защитой от этой уязвимости. Кто может помочь? Не знаю, есть тут платный раздел?

Прочитаны ссылки https://www.corelan.be/index.php/articles/ ,
отсюда почти весь раздел Exploit Writing Tutorials относится к нашей теме

Также ссылка https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20497/stack-overflows-defeating-canaries-aslr-dep-nx

Теоретически всё понятно, но не получается сформулировать задание в целом.

Comment: @Marina_L, ХэшКод это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.

Comment: @Marina_L, ХэшКод это не фриланс биржа. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, уточните, что сделали сами, что не получилось.

Comment: Можно узнать учебное зведение, в котором вы учитесь. Еще ни разу не встричал столь интересных тем у студентов.

Comment: Как перефразировать вопрос? Материал теоретический изучен, но задача стоит придумать лабораторную работу для студентов. Надо написать приложение с уязвимостью, а задание будет -  решение, как ее обойти.

Comment: @Marina_L, Вам надо придумать *названия* и *текст описывающий, что требуется сделать* для 2-х студенческих лаб?

- в первой требуется написать программу, которая, например, читает файл + делает какие-то действия над прочитанным содержимым (при этом программа имеет дефект, вызывающий переполнение буфера) и сделать такой файл, что программа, скажем, напечатает "Hello HackWorld!";

- во второй нужно разработать программу, которая ...  как-то разруливает ситуацию ...
(вот тут я не знаю).

Что-то в таком духе?

--

Кстати, а при чем здесь именно C++11?

Скорее всего все изюминки будут на asm.

Comment: Надо сделать следующее: написать приложение
в нем есть защита от уязвимости, 
а задание это устранить эту защиту или обойти ее в этом приложении
то есть может его надо открыть в какой-то программе скаченной
и там уже изменить код
чтото в этом духе

Comment: @avp: Судя по всему, для выполнения заданий придётся хорошо изучить кодогенератор какого-то конкретного компилятора C++. Ну и судя по всему подробности имплементации защиты (`VirtualProtect` под Windows etc).

Comment: @VladD, вряд ли это хорошее задание для **лабы**. 

Ну, я бы еще понял, что-то вроде -- *затереть адрес возврата так, что бы управление передалось на ...*

--

imho она должна делаться за несколько часов (после освоения соответствующего материала) (а может я просто недооцениваю уровень студентов?).

Comment: @avp: Ну может, направление обучения «защита информации»? А так, для обыкновенного программиста такие тонкости обычно не преподают.